# Associating ssh public key with user account

Tags: ssh

How do I associate an ssh public key with a user account on the machine I connect to, so I don't have to type in the account password every time I make an ssh connection to that machine?

The machine being connected to is an older mini with Leopard installed. I assume that this is doable in Leopard, and I don't have to upgrade to Snow Leopard or Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you create a public and private key (if you haven't done so already) on the machine *from* which you want to login:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

You only need to do this if there isn't already a `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` file.

On Linux, there's the `ssh-copy-id` helper. On Mac, you need to copy the public key by hand:

- Copy the generated public key to the target machine:

  `scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user@targetmachine:myPublicKey.pub`
- Login to the target machine:

  `ssh user@targetmachine`
- Append the public key to the authorized keys:

  `cat myPublicKey.pub >>.ssh/authorized_keys`
- You can now delete the copied key:

  `rm myPublicKey.pub`
- Done. You should now be able to login to your target machine without the need to enter a password.

Comment: If you have never set up an authorized_keys on the remote host, you can save a little bit of time by simply doing;

`scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user@remotehost:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: @VxJasonxV: Right, but now that I think about it there's even a way to collapse all the bullet-points into one line, even with appending: `ssh user@targetmachine 'cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys' <~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` But I think the step-by-step solution in my answer is easier to understand.

Comment: It is, by far :).

Answer (score 1):

You should have an `id_dsa.public` file in your `~/.ssh` folder.

Just copy that file over to the server, into `~/.ssh` folder and append its contents to the `authorized_keys` file.

Your next login should be automatic. It can be that you're asked about the password you used to created the private key, but there's an option to store that password into your keychain.